# CURL post request to C# post request

Tags: c#, http-post

Could you please help me to make a post request in c#. Here is curl:

```
curl -X POST https://api.test.com/call \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Token token=YOUR_TOKEN" \
  -d '{"amount":10.00, "id":"123", "customer":{"external_id":"100"}, "receiver":{"external_id":"200"}}'
```

I tried doing this:

```
string myJson = "{"amount":10.00, "id":"123", "customer":{"external_id":"100"}, "receiver":{"external_id":"200"}}";
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.test.com");                    
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIAccessToken", "myToken");               
                    var content = new StringContent(myJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.test.com/call/", content);
                    resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
```

But getting bad request response 400 Error. I am new to this, will appreciate your help.

Comment: You are not adding `Authorization` header in C# code

Comment: I tried `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "myToken");` still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.test.com/call/", content);
```

Should be:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("call", content);
```

Also, looks like your JSON isn't properly escaped. Try:

```
string myJson = "{\"amount\":10.00, \"id\":\"123\", \"customer\":{\"external_id\":\"100\"}, \"receiver\":{\"external_id\":\"200\"}}";
```

And you haven't declared your result variable

```
// Missing var
var resultContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Basically, the example you posted shouldn't even compile...

Comment: changed to `var response = await client.PostAsync("call/", content);`, still same issue.

Comment: I tried to make a post request in postman and it works, the only thing is it return 401 error - my token might be wrong. But when I run my code I am getting bad request response.

Comment: Noticed a couple of other things - have a look at the modified answer.

Comment: I declared resultContent  I just did not add it here. Thank you. There was errorin my Json. fixed it. ! :)